# Knockout.js options custom data-something

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Is there any way in Knockoutjs binding where I can specify custom data- in options?

```
<select data-bind="options: filtered, value: value, optionsText: 'Text', optionsValue: 'Value', 'data-something': 'Description' }"></select>
```

and this results:

```
<option value="foo" data-something="description">Text</option>
```

Please do reply.

Answer (score 1):

[Custom Binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html)

```
<select data-bind="createDropDown: filtered"></select>
```

Then add this custom binding method, where you can process the array yourself and manually add each option to the select:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.yourBindingName =
{
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext)
    {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(valueAccessor(), function (item)
        {
            $(element).append('<option value="' + item[value] + '" data-something="' + item[description] + '">' + item[text] + '</option>');
        });
    }
};
```

I've not tested this, but you should get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for?

```
<select data-bind="foreach: filtered">
    <option data-bind="text: Text, attr: {value: Value, 'data-something': Description}"></option>
</select>
```